# Differentiating between "written" and "writing"

Tags: word-choice, orthography, tenses

For some reason it is *written* and *writing*. It's confusing to me.

How can I remember to write them differently?

Comment: This is a nonsense question. Voting to close.

Comment: Or else, downvoting.

Comment: Differently from *what*? There's one T in *write*, and there's one T in *writing*. Easy as pie. (Now, I do have a rough idea of what you might be aiming at, but as long as you don't actually specify it, the question is quite nonsensical indeed, and the answer to it is just "I don't know where you even got the idea that it should be *writting*, that's totally wrong, just stop doing it".)

Comment: I wonder how many realize the asker may be confused about how the past participle, *written*, is written.

Comment: @RegDwight: There's one T in "put", and there's one T in "putting".  Oops.  ;-)

Comment: This question looks almost like a Swiftian nost-thumb at those of us who sometimes city Google as a source of usage data :-)  There are also some real gems among the results for *writting*, eg an advertisement at [Essays R Easy](http://essaysreasy.com/content/thesis-writting.html) offering help (at $9.50/page) with your ‘thesis writting’.  Although admittedly this seems to be not an accident but a deliberate mis-spelling, casting their net wide to pick up on all the mis-speled searches they can…

Comment: I disagree with you guys, for some reason its written and writing. so its confusing and I'm asking how to remember the correct version.

Comment: @jae: that is exactly what this question is *not* asking. @010: now we're talking. Please edit your question accordingly, so that it actually makes sense. That is all we are asking for.

Comment: @RegDwight now better? if you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Writing` is the right word; `writting` is the misspelling of `writing`.

Look at the pattern:

- `Write` – pronounced  `rIt` (`i` is long) – single `t`.
- `Writer` – pronounced  `rIt-u(r)` (`i` is long) – single `t`.
- `Writing` – pronounced  `rIt-ing` (`i` is long) – single `t`.
- `Written` – pronounced `ri-t(u)n` (`i` is **short**) – double `t`.

Comment: so its only, because of pronunciation? the "written" makes it really confusing and hard to remember.

Comment: @010, I'm not sure why you'd say *only* because of pronunciation. English spelling is often taken to task for being idiosyncratic, and you're complaining because it's coherent, for once? :)

Answer (score 4):

Google is not "unsure" about it; read the results of both:

http://www.google.com/search?q=writting
returns 7 million results, with the top results including "Writting is a shockingly common misspelling of 'writing'", "English teachers dread to see ...". Most other results are amateur poetry or spam sites. Google also asks "Did you mean: 'writing'?"

http://www.google.com/search?q=writing returns over 30 times as many results, with top hits references to authors and publications.

When Google (or any web search) turns up results, you have to actually read them to see if it's what you want. Spelling is no different.

Comment: +1. Google makes it harder and harder to search for a specific spelling of a word, and thus becomes less and less useful for corpus research (if it ever was) and checking grammar and spelling. It helps if you search for this: [+writing -writting] and compare its results with [-writing +writting].

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the [Common Errors in English Usage](http://www.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/errors.html), it is "**writing**":

> One of the comments English teachers dread to see on their evaluations is “The professor really helped me improve my writting.”
>
> When “`-ing`” is added to a word which ends in a short vowel followed only by a single consonant, that consonant is normally doubled, **but “write” has a silent E on the end** to ensure the long I sound in the word. Doubling the T in this case would make the word rhyme with “flitting.”

Answer (score 1):

The present participle of the verb *to write* is **writing** (pronounced |ˈrīti ng | in American English), while the past participle is **written** (pronounced |ˈritn| in American English). Examples:

> - I am *writing* an essay.
> - I have *written* the essay.
> - I have finished *writing* it.
> - It is *written*...